# Is it legal for someone on an H1B to found a startup?

Tags: corporate-law, immigration

I have a friend sponsored on an H1B visa that I'd like to start to a software company with. We would not be securing outside capital. I'm wondering if the terms of an H1B visa which I believe prevent outside employment would prohibit being a founding member of a firm that didn't provide compensation, but only equity?

Does an H1B allow him to render programming skills and operate in the capacity of a founding member if he's not being "paid" or showing income.